# How to scrape off a .jsp website?

Tags: web, web-scraping

I am looking to scrape a table into Excel from this website 
http://www.crisil.com/ratings/nsic-rating-list.jsp

it has about 5000 rows running into several pages (from 1 to 547), how do i get these rows into Excel without doing a copy paste every time?

Answer (score -1):

look into these links. if you can get the html table name from page source, i think this might work

https://eagereyes.org/data/scrape-tables-using-google-docs

Comment: i tried to use the google docs ImportHtml as well as the excel functionality (data -> from Web). Both did not work – user1012249 just now

Comment: there is a mechanism called Excel VBA, visit this link and see
http://www.familycomputerclub.com/scrpae-pull-data-from-websites-into-excel.html